# responsibility of model in MVVM

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js, durandal

This question is more to do with how to structure the code or more precisely the responsibility of models in a MVVM pattern using Knockout. I am using Knockout with Durandal but the question could be a generic question for a MVVM  pattern. For e.g

I have model as such:

```
var Model = function(data){
      this.name = data.name;
      this.count = ko.observable();
};

Model.prototype.getCount = function(){
       var self = this;
       setInterval(function(){
             //some ajax call to get the count
             self.count(data.count);
       }, 1000);

};
```

My viewModel takes a collection of my models like:

```
var ViewModel = function(){
       this.models = ko.observableArray([]);
       //ajax call to get the required data
       data.Items.forEach(function(item){
             var model = new Model(item);    
             model.getCount();
             this.models.push(model); 
       }
};
```

And now my view

```
<div data-bind="foreach: models">
    <div data-bind="text: name"></div>
    <div data-bind="text: count"></div>
</div>
```

My question is because my model has an observable property and whenever the property changes it updates the view. But in essence it is an model and should the responsibility of updating the UI rest solely on the view-model.

So should the code relating to updating the count essentially **getCount**, live on the view-model and the model is not the right place for it. Where's the distinction of what code should stay in viewModel or the model.

Comment: Model represents entities in your system whereas ViewModel is a model for UI.
Model should interact with persistency/backend to update itself. ViewModel would make a bridge between Model and UI (2 way).

backend <-> Model <-> ViewModel <-> View

Comment: My model in the above case interacts with backend to update it's count value plus it also has a observable property which has a two way binding to the view. But after the reading the answer below I am more inclined to thinking it as viewModel. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: for UI binding, your Model and ViewModel are both ViewModel. However, don't forget Model is domain model e.g. User, Product etc, whereas ViewModel is specific to UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would class your Model as a view model, to be honest. Your model is the json objects you get back from your Ajax call, and you create a view model for each of those. There is no issue with having nested view models, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: I have given some thought about the whole concept and your answer plus with other's, has helped me iron out the doubts and confusions I was having. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Knockout doesn't truly implement MVVM; it's more like VVM. Other libraries like Backbone, et al, use models; Knockout really doesn't. Your "Model" for the sake of MVVM in Knockout is your server-side database entity.

Comment: Granted the server side entity is the model, but you could decorate that entity with more properties (computed, etc.). Your viewmodel is essentially the bridge between that model and your view, so actions on the view will be handled by the viewmodel and it is responsible for making changes to the underlying model. So ViewModel is something that contains the model and makes it available to the view. Hence, Mode-View-ViewModel. Do you agree?

Comment: I think you're looking at more of a conversion than a true model, though. If you pass the model to the view and "decorate it", or even if you don't modify it at all (though that would be odd), it's still a "view model" now, rather than a model. You could perhaps make the argument that it briefly exists client-side as you instantiate the view model, but it's pretty much thrown away afterwards. To update the model, you're going to be issuing AJAX POSTs to modify the server-side entity, *not* some client-side version of it.

Comment: Rightly put. I agree there.